# Как обратиться к label который находится на пользовательском элементе управления?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

Доброго времени суток.
Пишу с таким вот вопросом: Создал пользовательский элемент управления и поместил на него label, далее поместил пользовательский элемент управления на форму и хочу, чтобы по щелчку по кнопке (которая расположена на форме) выводилось значение текста Lable в textBox на форме. (хотя на скриншотах другая задача, но суть не меняется.. нужно получить значение текста в lable)
[image: Так выглядит пользовательский элемент управления]
[image: Так выглядит код кнопки расположенной на форме]
Как обратиться к label пользовательского элемента управления?
Кто знает - пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: Добавте ваш код прямо в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Все, проблема решена!) Я создал открытое поле, которому присваивался текст из IDlbl  и удалял уже данные из базы по значению этого поля.[image: Созданное поле][image: Его инициализация]
[image: Обращение к значению поля]

Comment: Решение, конечно, рабочее. Но всё-таки лучше сделать свойство вместо поля. И используйте параметры в sql-запросах, во избежание sql-инъекций.